# Any reason why I can't target the Archive dropdown in Wordpress using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

By default, the Archives widget in Wordpress generates a dropdown menu that outputs thus:

```
<select id="archives-dropdown-2" name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"></select>
```

I want to add a class to this (as I'm using Bootstrap), so rather than create my own plugin to generate the dropdown, I just thought using jQuery to add a class to the element would work fine.

However, in the most simplest of forms, this doesn't seem to make any changes (either with or without double quotes around *archive-dropdown*:

```
$('select[name=archive-dropdown]').addClass('form-control');
```

What's the reason it's not being targeted, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you know if the `<select>` is generated by JavaScript? It could be that the element doesn't exist when your script is trying to target it.

Comment: The element is probably loaded later with ajax, or is in an iframe. Check that.

Comment: Hmm it looks like it. Because it's part of the Wordpress core, not sure how I can filter or hook into the output either. I was hoping to not have to create my own function.